# Python3.5 = syntax error subprocess run

Tags: python, wordpress, subprocess

i want use wp cli in python3.5. but  always my IDE PyScripter get Syntax Error
i try

```
from subprocess import run
```

i want run this command, or similar with wp-cli

```
wp post create --meta_input='{"_thumbnail_id":"6"}' --post_title='titolo di prova' --post_content='ma che bello funziona tutto' --post_status='publish'
```

how should I write it?

Comment: don't be ashamed: show us your attempt in python & the error location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this pass on the shell command as list of strings, like if you want to do 'ls -l'

```
subprocess.run(['ls','-l'])
```

for your case try this,

```
subprocess.run(["wp","post","create","--meta_input='{"_thumbnail_id":"6"}'","--post_title='titolo di prova'","--post_content='ma che bello funziona tutto'","--post_status='publish'"])
```

Incase you dont want to write such big code, do this,

```
string = "wp post create --meta_input='{"_thumbnail_id":"6"}' --post_title='titolo di prova' --post_content='ma che bello funziona tutto' --post_status='publish'"
```

use duble quotes to write it as string,then

```
l = string.split(" ")
subprocess.run(l)
```

Comment: first OP wants to use `run` not `call`, then the single quotes in the argument list makes it difficult for me to believe that it'll work

Comment: you can try it, just replace call with run, it should work.